# How can I solve the error 'Android resource linking failed'?

Tags: android

Hi I'm facing a problem while running my app

Android resource linking failed

@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute srcCompat (attr) reference.

this problem is occuring in the given Imageview tag please help me

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/memeView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/shareButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
    />
```

Comment: srcCompat needs to be a drawable reference.  I don't know why you tried to link to a tool.  I'm not even sure what you're trying to do, as tools aren't a resource type.  If you're trying to link to a drawable in your app or a library, there's no need for the tools in there.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
app:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
```

with

```
tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
```